What is the Python code to check all the GenerativeAI models supported by Google Gemini?
Being new to GenerativeAI world, I am trying to load a pre-trained text generation model and doing some stuff which is not working. This is how I load the GenerativeAI model.
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel
generation_model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")

Since it does not work, I feel I might have to use some other GenerativeAI model, not "gemini-pro". Even I try following piece of code to check all the models supported by Gemini.
import google.generativeai as genai
for model in genai.list_models():
    if 'generateContent' in model.supported_generation_methods:
        print(model.name)

But I get 'PermissionDenied' error as attached image shows.

Now as a programmer I have 2 queries here.
Q1. Can I see the GenerativeAI models supported by Gemini or not?
Q2. If answer is 'Yes', what is the Python code?

First question:  Do you want to use Vertex or AI studio Gemini.  You seam to be mixing two different APIs.   Second question:  What stuff do you want to do so far you just appear to be trying to list the models you have access to.

Yes I am doing different stuffs with GenerativeAI. But here my question is to check the models supported by Google Gemini.

List models sample for AI studio Gemini.   Did you forget the configure?
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

load_dotenv()
genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("API_KEY"))
genai.configure(transport='grpc')

def list_models():
    for i, m in zip(range(5), genai.list_models()):
        print(f"Name: {m.name} Description: {m.description} support: {m.supported_generation_methods}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_models()


Looks I have missed the configuration part in my code. I will check it once and accept. But why 'PermissionDenied' error? 'ConfigurationError' should be more appropriate.

I cant tell you why google picks the error messages they do.  Wait until you hit 500 errors try and figure out what's causing them can be a fun time.


Setting generation_model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro") doesn't mean you're loading an AI model. It only sets internal SDK variables to use Vertex AI - Gen AI model's services.

For the most up-to-date information, I recommend using the google-cloud-aiplatform package https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-aiplatform . It's updated frequently, sometimes weekly. You can find helpful examples at https://cloud.google.com/docs/samples and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/generative_ai.

To learn about the latest Gemini model updates, refer to https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/learn/models. Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to fetch available models using the SDK at this time.

As a workaround, you can check the _GEMINI_STABLE_MODEL_NAMES variable in the VertexAI Tokenizer feature. Here's the source code link: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/819e9ff568798232282e1f6dcf180cff3c788c63/vertexai/tokenization/_tokenizer_loading.py#L38-L42. This is a workaround!


